# Getting multiple values from a dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read through multiple threads but none of them specifically speak to my issue. I have a table functioning as a dropdown. (Yes, it has to be this way)

```js
var blocka = "test1"
$('#john').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    this.checked = true;
  }
  if (this.checked) {
    //checkbox clicked is now checked
    var tx = document.getElementById('james').innerHTML;
    $('.variant_title').text(tx);
  }
  if (this.checked) {
    //checkbox clicked is now checked
    var rx = document.getElementById('matt').innerhtml;
    $('.variant_price').text(rx);
  } else {
    this.setAttribute("checked", ""); // For IE
    this.removeAttribute("checked"); // For other browsers
    this.checked = false;
    $('.variant_title').empty();
    $('.variant_price').empty();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="special-select">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="selecter-selected variant_title" name="click_me" style="height:40px! important;"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="picker" class="select-closed" style="font-size:.75rem;float:left! 
     important;min-height:1.20em;">
      <td><input id="john" name="updates[31435395282]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - <span id="matt">$0.01</span></td>
      <td id="james" class="hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="picker" class="select-closed" style="font-size:.75rem;float:left! 
    important;min-height:1.20em;">
      <td><input id="john" name="updates[31435395346]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - <span id="matt">$0.01</span></td>
      <td id="james" class="hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="picker" class="select-closed" style="font-size:.75rem;float:left! 
    important;min-height:1.20em;">
      <td><input id="john" name="updates[31435395410]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - <span id="matt">$0.01</span></td>
      <td id="james" class="hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <div class="variant_price"></div>
</table>
```

the code I am using to get the value of  'james' is working for the first checkbox input. However, when I uncheck the input and try to check a new one I get no value showing for the variant_title.

How do I get it to work for more than the first iteration?

Comment: Post the returned HTML, not the pre-rendered, that doesnt help us help you.

Comment: I added values @Cam

Comment: This isn't the solution to your problem, but `innerhtml` ≠ `innerHTML`.

Comment: oh ok thanks @JordanRunning I'm still learning a lot of this stuff

Comment: @JordanRunning I changed it to lowercase in my actual code and that actually made it not work at all

Comment: Lowercase is incorrect. `innerHTML` is correct.

Comment: What is the expected behavior when more than one checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same `id` multiple times. `id`s must be unique, which makes them unsuited for what you're using them for. When you do `document.getElementById('james')`, which `#james` do you expect it to get? When multiple elements are the same "kind" of thing, use a `class`, not an `id`.

As an aside, `james`, `john`, and `matt` are not useful `id`s. `id`s and class names should be descriptive. In the below snippet I've replaced `<span id="matt">` with `<span class="price">` and `<td id="james">` with `<td class="title">`.

In the code below, when a checkbox is checked, I use jQuery's `closest` function to get the checkbox's row and `find` to get the `.title` and `.price` in the same row. (I've also simplified the markup and logic to make it clearer; you'll need to integrate it with what you have.)

Since you didn't specify, in the snippet when a second checkbox is checked it just replaces the output from the previous check.

```js
var $variantTitle = $('.variant_title');
var $variantPrice = $('.variant_price');

$('#products :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var title = $row.find('.title').text();
    var price = $row.find('.price').text();
    $variantTitle.text(title);
    $variantPrice.text(price);
  } else {
    $variantTitle.empty();
    $variantPrice.empty();
  }
});
```

```css
body{font-size:.75rem}
.hide{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="variant_title"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395282]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395346]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="updates[31435395410]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - <span class="price">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="title hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="variant_price"></div>
```

Comment: @JCQ50 Glad to help. If this answer solved your problem please consider marking it as Accepted.

Comment: Do you know how I would get it add the prices together?@jordanrunning

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be unique in HTML, and it will only get the 1st match so that's why it only works for the 1st one.

1st thing to do is make id unique if you really need use id, use `id="john1"`, `id="john2"`... etc.

`$('input[id^=john]')` will get all input with id started with john (attribute selector), so all john1 john2 will be selected.

Then set tx rx to '' first, then find all checked checkbox with:

```
  $('.picker input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var parentTr = $(this).parent().parent();
    tx += '<br>' + parentTr.find('.james').text();
    rx += '<br>' + parentTr.find('.matt').text();
  });
```

Since the checkbox is grandchild of tr, child of td `$(this).parent().parent();` will get the grandparent tr, then use `find('.james')` you can find the class called james within this tr block.

build the string and finally output as html()

```js
var blocka = "test1";
$('input[id^=john]').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    this.checked = true;
  }
  var tx = '';
  var rx = '';
  $('.picker input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    var parentTr = $(this).parent().parent();
    tx += '<br>' + parentTr.find('.james').text();
    rx += '<br>' + parentTr.find('.matt').text();
  });
  $('.variant_title').html(tx);
  $('.variant_price').html(rx);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="special-select">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="selecter-selected variant_title" name="click_me" style="height:40px! important;"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="select-closed picker" style="font-size:.75rem;float:left! 
     important;min-height:1.20em;">
      <td>
        <input id="john1" name="updates[31435395282]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - <span class="matt">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="james hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / S - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="select-closed picker" style="font-size:.75rem;float:left! 
    important;min-height:1.20em;">
      <td>
        <input id="john2" name="updates[31435395346]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - <span class="matt">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="james hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / M - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="select-closed picker" style="font-size:.75rem;float:left! 
    important;min-height:1.20em;">
      <td>
        <input id="john3" name="updates[31435395410]" type="checkbox" value="31435395282:" />&nbsp;</td>
      <td>MAPerformance Hoodie - Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - <span class="matt">$0.01</span></td>
      <td class="james hide">Unisex Hoodie / Black / L - $0.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="variant_price"></div>
```

Comment: the only issue is there is only one id the code uses dynamic values to create the multiple options. My original code I posted showed that put i had to change it to get a answer that might help.

Comment: @JCQ50 add a counter when you create those id, like `index` for ex: id = `"james"`+`index`